# When submitting a post via praw, how do I return the url of that post?

Tags: python, bots, praw

I'm using the following code to submit a self post. Once that is submitted I would like the url to that post to be stored in a variable. I'm new to python and praw so i'm probably missing something obvious.

```
import praw

sub_reddit = 'test'
user_agent = 'user agent info'
post_title = 'post title text'
post_body = 'post body text'

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)

def login():
    r.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

def self_post():
    r.submit(sub_reddit, post_title, text=post_body)

login()
self_post()
```

Looking through the documentation I found [this](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html#praw.__init__.SubmitMixin.submit) that states the return of .submit is as follows:

> "The newly created Submission object if the reddit instance
>   can access it. Otherwise, return the url to the submission.

If that is the case, how do I get that link? I can't run a lot of different test because the API has a limit on submissions so I keep getting blocked from trying new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return the response and assign it to a variable:

```
def self_post():
    return r.submit(sub_reddit, post_title, text=post_body)

login()
resp = self_post()
```

Answer (score 1):

After you submit the link, you can use [`.short_link`](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Submission.short_link) to get the URL to the submission:

```
submission = r.submit(sub_reddit, post_title, text=post_body)
submission.short_link
```